# How to programmatically generate an html page with jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

The contents of colors.jade:

```
html
  body
    for color in colors
      p color
```

The contents of genHtml.js:

```
var jade = require('jade');
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

var html = jade.renderFile('colors.jade', {globals: [colors] });
console.log(html);
```

When you run `node genHtml.js`, you receive this error:

```
TypeError: colors.jade:3
    1| html
    2|   body
  > 3|     for color in colors
    4|       p color
    5| 

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

How would you make the colors array available to the jade compiler?

Relevant reference: http://jade-lang.com/api/

Comment: You're passing colors array into an array so remove the extra brackets, and globals key should be renamed to colors.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `colors` array into an array so remove the extra brackets, and `globals` key should be renamed to `colors`. Also have the `=` before `color` to output the value.

Tested and working:

colors.jade

```
  html
      body
        for color in colors
          p=color
```

genHtml.js

```
var jade = require('jade');
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

var html = jade.renderFile('colors.jade', { colors: colors });
console.log(html);
```

stdout

```
<html><body><p>red</p><p>blue</p><p>green</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, jade overloads the second argument `options` to include the `locals`.  Also, `renderFile` doesn't return the html, the html is returned in the callback.   You should use:

```
var  jade = require('jade');
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

jade.renderFile('colors.jade', { colors: colors }, function(err, html) {
    // if err...
    console.log(html);
});
```

(this is untested, but should work)

Comment: Okay, looks like it may optionally return the html value, however I'd highly recommend against that since that would make it a synchronous function due to the loading of the file from the file system.